# Calculate weekly growth curve, and estimate numbers if growing x% faster per week

Tags: microsoft-excel

How would I calculate the current growth curve and then estimate the new growth curve and weekly numbers if each week was growing 5% faster than actually recorded.

Given I have:

- table of weekly sales dollars
- A known constant that we have lost 5% of our weekly sales due to a software glitch

I would like to have another column of "expected" that follows the new curve...

[image: table of example data]

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem?

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp5yFpzAJ7g&app=desktop